# распознание объекта по цвету, раздельные рамки для нескольких объектов

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv, color

Есть скрипт по распознанию заданного цвета. Хорошо работает если объект один, а если два, то рамка выделения просто увеличивается и захватывает два объекта. Как эту рамку разбить для каждого объекта чтоб своя была,а не одна общая.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image

from random import randrange

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Color Chooser')
root.geometry('300x150')

c1, c2, c3 = '', '', ''

def change_color():
    global c1,c2,c3
    colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
    c1 = str(colors[0]).split(',')[0]
    c1 = ''.join(c1.split('(', 1)[1]) #Red
    c2 = str(colors[0]).split(',')[1]
    c2 = ''.join(c2.split(' ', 1)[1]) #Green
    c3 = str(colors[0]).split(',')[2]
    c3 = ''.join(c3.split(')')[0])
    c3 = ''.join(c3.split(' ', 1)[1]) #Blue
    root.configure(bg=colors[1])

def color_hsv():
    blue = int(c3)
    green = int(c2)
    red = int(c1)
    color = np.uint8([[[blue, green, red]]])
    hsv_color = cv2.cvtColor(color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hue = hsv_color[0][0][0]

    color_box = [(0,0,255),(0,255,255),(0,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,0,0)]
    c_num = randrange(5)

    img = cv2.imread('Blue.jpg', 1)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_range = np.array([hue - 10 if hue-10>0 else 0, 70, 70], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_range = np.array([hue + 10 if hue+10<179 else 179, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
    mask_ = Image.fromarray(mask)
    bbox = mask_.getbbox()
    if bbox is not None:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), color_box[c_num], 2)

    #cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    while (1):
        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if (k == 27):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ttk.Button(root, text='Select a Color', command=change_color).pack(expand=True)
ttk.Button(root, text='Find objects', command=color_hsv).pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Значение hue  бывает от 0 до 179... Поэтому hue+10<255 будет всегда...

Comment: @AlexAlex Благодарю за подсказку, подправил, но вопроса это не решает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я решил вопрос таким образом, если есть решение лучше, буду рад увидеть.

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), (x1+x2,y1+y2), color_box[c_num], 2)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
```